# Should I, and if so, what should I bring, for my last day at work

Tags: job-change

I'm starting a new job in the new year, and therefore quitting my current job.

This is my first job change since I finished my education, and I'm leaving on really good standing. My current employer told me that if my new employer doesn't behave, I can always come back.

My first thought was to bring something like donuts, but due to Christmas the office is overflowing with candy and snacks of all sorts, and we already have a meeting with breakfast in the morning, and another in the afternoon with burgers. So I don't really think more food is necessary.

To summarize:
Should I bring something for my co-workers on my last day at work?
What should I bring?

Edit: Alcoholic beverages would definitely be a possibility.
The company is small (fewer than 15 people, including management) there's a great atmosphere where we can spend an evening playing games together (cs:go, mtg, mariocart etc.) it is mostly young unsettled employees, with me being one of the few that's settled down with wife and kids.
All of them are great people, and if it wasn't for the commute I would probably not have switched.

Comment: Depending on culture, alcohol might be appropriate. A couple of bottles of wine to share a drink with your colleagues on your last day is not unheard of in Australia, but also requires the right culture for it to be appropriate.

Comment: Another idea might be to take some of the co-workers you’re close with out to a meal.

Comment: I think the answer here would too heavily depend on company culture for us to be able to advise you on whether you should take something and what that should be.

Comment: @dukeling i tried adding some context to the post that might clarify ;-)

Comment: @AffableAmbler the company is so small that I would feel bad if I didn't invite them all, and I can't really afford bringing them all, to anything higher than McDonald's, I think this would be the right answer had I been a manager or similar, but alas, I am but an office worker :)

Comment: @maybe_factor the culture definitely allows for this, and I am really considering if I could pull it off, without showing how much of a wine noob I am ;)

Comment: Honestly I would **bring nothing**.  The fact that you're leaving is somewhat ambiguous.  Just leave it alone.

Answer (score 3):

A handwritten note, a box of doughnuts, might cost less and offer the same sentiments.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it really is just the sentiments that matters I guess. I was pretty much stuck on thinking that snacks might be "excessive" with Christmas snacks and meeting refreshments already in place.

Answer (score 2):

As a low calorie alternative, the first working day after you leave have some flowers delivered addressed to the whole office with a suitable note.

Comment: I'm unsure if any of them are allergic, but we do have some plants at the office, and I really like the subtleties in waiting till the day after.

Answer (score 1):

## An office plant

[Office plants](https://smallbiztrends.com/2014/11/indoor-office-plants.html) can be a nice touch to show that you actually care about that office and want to leave something lasting

You'd have to check with people to see if they're willing to look after it, so long as you provide the plant food and watering can.

## Light décor

Something small such as a wall clock is also nice, it shows your willingness to contribute to the office space, whether you're there or not.

## Wine

Wine is something a lot of people resort to, yet is appreciated by the recipients.

Make sure that you consider those who don't want to partake as well as serving size enough to get around.

## Anything small

A box of chocolates, some dessert, flowers or any sort of token you feel worthy will go a long way to making your [soon to be] ex-coworkers feel appreciated.

---

you can preface these with either a small note or by telling them that it's "something to remember me by".